GSAP Timeline with Locomotive Scroll not working in Next.js
I'm trying to implement a GSAP timeline with Locomotive Scroll to pin an element while scrolling in a Next.js component. The code works perfectly in a normal HTML and JS environment, but it's not functioning as expected in Next.js.
Normal html environment:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/gsap-timeline-forked-3dqjgv?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js
Next JS component:
import React, { useRef, useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import gsap from "gsap";
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";
import styles from "./services.module.css";

function Services() {
  const elToPin = useRef(null);
  const pinPosition = useRef(null);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

    const tl = gsap.timeline({
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: pinPosition.current,
        start: "top top",
        end: "bottom top",
        pin: elToPin.current,
        scrub: true,
        markers: true,
      },
    });

    window.addEventListener("progressEvent", (e) => {
      const { progress } = e.detail;
      tl.progress(progress);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <div className="container">
        <div ref={pinPosition} className={styles.services} id="services">
          <div ref={elToPin} className={styles.title}>
            Expert Guidance for a <span>Smoother</span> Transition
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}

export default Services


.services {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 4rem;
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

.title {
  color: var(--primary-color);
  font-size: var(--title-font-size);
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


Expected Behavior:
The "PIN ME" text element should be pinned to the viewport while scrolling through the section with the blueviolet background.
Actual Behavior:
Before starting the trigger it's creating a lot of empty space above the component and and the title is staying there. And when its enter on trigger start position the pin elemnt moves to the trigger end position instantly.


Next.js: "14.2.3"
GSAP: "^3.12.5"
Locomotive Scroll: "^5.0.0-beta.13"
I've tried using the useLayoutEffect and useEffect hook to initialize Locomotive Scroll and GSAP after the component mounts. However, the pinning functionality is still not working.
[NOTE]: I couldn't find locomotive scroll beta in codepen dependencies to make a demo for next js.
